# ios How to use a webproxy to load uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

Any of you knows how can I load a uiwebview using proxys inside of the app?

```
NSURL *site =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:site];
    [_webLoad loadRequest:request];
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this one:

https://github.com/pokeb/ProxyingUIWebView

Very simple to implement and fast to use. Take a look.

Comment: everytime I tried to load any url I got this error: 501 - Not implemented. No handler exists to handle http://127.0.0.1:8080/?url=http%3A%2f%2fgoogle.com . Even when I change this line in the proxy implementation file: location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://187.144.130.247:8080?url=%@",[[NSURL URLWithString:location relativeToURL:[[self realRequest] url]] absoluteString]];

Comment: isn't it a program conflict or incorrect http? maybe should be something in config settings or permitions acess?